# Calculate $\frac {1}{2\cdot3\cdot 4}+\frac {1}{3\cdot4\cdot 5}+\frac {1}{4\cdot5\cdot 6}+\frac {1}{5\cdot6\cdot 7}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

[image]

Calculate the following sum.

$$\frac {1}{2\cdot3\cdot 4}+\frac {1}{3\cdot4\cdot 5}+\frac {1}{4\cdot5\cdot 6}+\frac {1}{5\cdot6\cdot 7}$$

My attempt

$$\sum =\frac {5\cdot 6\cdot 7+2\cdot6\cdot 7+2\cdot3\cdot 7+2\cdot3\cdot 4}{7!}=\frac 1{14}$$

But, this calculation seems ugly. Is there a good way?

Comment: I'm confused. Does this sum go on forever? Or is it just those 4 terms?

Comment: If it's just those 4 terms, then 1/24 + 1/60 + 1/120 + 1/210 = 1/14.

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2F%282*3*4%29%2B1%2F%283*4*5%29%2B1%2F%284*5*6%29%2B1%2F%285*6*7%29)

Comment: OP: Are you just concerned about doing the arithmetic?

Comment: I will flag my questions because I get serial downvoting

Comment: @BrianTung Of course not.

Comment: Well, then, I'm afraid I don't understand your confusion, because you seem to have done everything correctly. I suppose if this problem went on for $100$ terms, you wouldn't want to do that arithmetic! In that case, nonstudent's answer below gives a good way to telescope the sum. (I think that would be a good way to avoid down-votes, because it's not as though you haven't done the work: Indicate that your issue is that the arithmetic, though trivial, doesn't *scale*, and you don't like the fact that if there were thousands of terms, you wouldn't know how to proceed.)

Comment: Otherwise, it's not really all that clear to the reader what your concern is. I don't know that I would consider the sum of four terms to be *ugly*, as that's a judgment call, but it's clear that the naive calculation doesn't scale without computational aid.

Comment: It is a bit work to do that by hand (without electronic help, otherwise the question is pointless anyway) , but basically everyone should in principle be able to do it. Is this just a question whether you added those terms correctly ? If you tried it , THEN you can check it with a calculator (unless of course in a test where calculators are not allowed). In short, I share Brian's confusion.

Comment: @Peter please see my question.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}=\frac 12\left (\frac 1{n(n+1)}-\frac 1{(n+1)(n+2)}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

The calculation is not as difficult as it seems:

$$5\cdot 6\cdot 7+2\cdot6\cdot 7+2\cdot3\cdot 7+2\cdot3\cdot 4\\=6(35+14+7+4)\\=6\cdot60\\=6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3$$

Which gives you

$$\frac{6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3}{7!}=\frac{1}{7\cdot2}=\frac{1}{14}$$